# recursive function with user input arrray(JAVA)

Tags: java, recursion

I'm trying to figure out how to pass variables from my main method to another one?

My main goal is to make a recursive program that passes user input into an array.Then prints out the largest integer using a recursive function.This is what I have so far.

```
import java.io.* ;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class MaxElement {



public static void main(String args[]){

// Initialize the number array
int[] Number;


 Number = new int [5];

 Scanner lop = new Scanner(System.in);
 System.out.println(" Please enter 5 numbers.");

String a= lop.nextLine();
 int f = Integer.parseInt(a);
Number[0]=f;
System.out.println("Enter 4 more numbers.");

String b= lop.nextLine();
 int g = Integer.parseInt(b);
Number[1]=g;
System.out.println("Enter 3 more numbers.") ;

String c= lop.nextLine();
 int h = Integer.parseInt(c);
Number[2]=h;
System.out.println("Enter 2 more numbers.");    

String d= lop.nextLine();
 int i = Integer.parseInt(d);
Number[3]=i;
System.out.println("Enter 1 more number.");

String e= lop.nextLine();
 int j = Integer.parseInt(e);
Number[4]=j;

lop.close();
System.out.println( f+g+h+i+j);
}
 void MaxElements() {
    MaxElement M = new MaxElement();
    M.f= k;
```

Comment: you can get lop.nextInt() rather than nextLine(). nextLine is for String. In that way you don't need to parse it.

Comment: Is there anything wrong with the way you're currently getting user input?

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to figure out how to pass variables from my main method to another one?

Here's a method.

```
private static String getName(BufferedReader input) {
    System.out.println("Do You Remember What Your Name Is?");
    try {
        String name = input.readLine();
        return name;
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
        return "";
    }
}
```

And here's what you would do in the main method.

```
    String name = getName(input);
```

A recursive method is simply a method that's called from inside the method until a condition is satisfied.  Your input code could be replaced by the following code.

```
package com.ggl.fse;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Recursive {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner lop = new Scanner(System.in);

        int length = 5;
        int[] numbers = new int[length];
        String s = "Please enter " + length + " numbers.";
        System.out.println(s);

        numbers = getNumbers(lop, numbers, 0, length);

        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            System.out.println(numbers[i]);
        }

        lop.close();
    }

    private static int[] getNumbers(Scanner lop, int[] numbers, 
            int index, int length) {
        String s = lop.nextLine();
        int a = Integer.parseInt(s);
        numbers[index] = a;

        if (index < (length - 1)) {
            s = "Enter " + (length - index - 1) + " more numbers.";
            System.out.println(s);
            getNumbers(lop, numbers, ++index, length);
        }

        return numbers;
    }

}
```

Comment: Gracias I learned several ways to the same thing and to call a method.

Answer (score 0):

import java.io.BufferedReader;

import java.io.IOException;

import java.io.InputStreamReader;

class Recursion
{

```
      static int max(int n,int max)
        {

            return n>max?n:max; 
        }

     static  int  test(int []a,int n,int max)
        {

            if(n==a.length)
             {
                 return max;
             }
           return test(a,n+1,max(a[n],max));



         }
public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException {
    InputStreamReader r=new InputStreamReader(System.in);  
    BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(r); 
    int arr[]=new int[7];
    System.out.print("enter the elements ");
    for(int i=0;i<6;i++)
    {
        arr[i]=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
    }

    int max=test(arr,0,0);
```

System.out.println(max);
    }

}